# creating a job in Kubernetes with an identifier as statefulset object at the same time

Tags: kubernetes

Can I create a Kubernetes job which also is a stateful object, meaning it will have its own identifier so I can communicate with that specific stateful instance and once it's done with its work the job will be deleted?

Comment: maybe create a crd?

Comment: You can create a Service that maps to any set of Pods and that should work here, if the Job container process happens to be running a server.

Comment: the thing is that I can have 100 of pods of the same type that should be stateful, do there job and then I would like to delete them... its not one service...

Comment: Like @DavidMaze suggested you can have a service or a label for the pods which you are planning to make stateful follow this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) for more information

Comment: But if I want to create a pod and then once it will finish its work it will finish, but still will be stateful, is that possible?

Comment: @Ohad yes in stateful sets the data will be stored on the persistent volume so your data will be safe.